# Setting environment variable TESSDATA_PREFIX in Tomcat

Tags: java, variables, tomcat, ocr, environment

We are using Tesseract OCR Java library called Tess4J. It works fine if run as a standalone application.   It needs a variable called TESSDATA_PREFIX which contains the tessdata config and other charset related files.

It also runs fine with embedded Tomcat 6 server in eclipse. I had set TESSDATA_PREFIX as an environment variable by using the launch configuration.

But when I package  everything into a WAR and drop it in deploy directory of tomcat, the environment variable does not seem to be picked and the server crashes the moment it encounters the doOCR api( which needs the tessdata config).

I tried setting this env variable inside catalina.bat and also thru command line, but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Environment variables in Tomcat should be put into a setenv.bat/setenv.sh script in the bin directory.

Comment: The setenv.bat was not present in Tomcat 6 bin. so i added this file and set the path,   
set TESSDATA_PREFIX="C:\apache-tomcat-6.0.32\lib\tessdata"
But it did not work.

Comment: @Vish - You restarted tomcat after you created the file right? If this doesn't work then the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Yes, tried that multiple times. Strange thing is the same stuff works fine with tomcat embedded in eclipse.

Comment: oh, it worked. i just added this line,  if defined TESSDATA_PREFIX set TESSDATA_PREFIX=C:\apache-tomcat-6.0.32\lib\  . Thanks Qwerky.

Comment: Hi, I also tried your solution, created setenv.bat and added this line: if defined TESSDATA_PREFIX set TESSDATA_PREFIX="C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-tomcat-7.0.47_32bit\lib\" but it didn't work..

Comment: My mistake: it should have bee without quotes. Thanks for the question and comments!